# SSH DEBIAN - Connection timeout

Tags: ssh, debian, connection, timeout

I have a problem with connection to my server (Debian).
For example, putty give me "Network error: connection time out"

I checked:

[ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiYTC.png)

[ulw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnmei.png)

[iptables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJZkU.png)

oddly enough, after restarting the server I can connect, but after a few minutes disconnects me and I can't anymore.

Please help.

Comment: Is your server maybe suspending itself or putting the network card in a low power mode?